# Calculate the score of the game "GO"

Tags: algorithm, logic

Does anyone know how to calculate the score in the game of [Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28game%29) programmatically?
I have an array of 19x19 and each element of this array can be 0 (empty point), 1 (black stone) or 2 (white stone). I don't understand how can I check the region to belong to any color.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question and add your attempts, and where you got stuck.

Comment: Do you want to count all "solid" regions, or do you want to try guessing regions that players would recognize to belong to one of them but possibly contain enemy's stone inside?

Comment: If it's just recognizing if a region is adjacent to stones of one and only one color, you should be able to easily program it traveling through the board array the way you'd trace it with a finger and marking regions with proper values.

Comment: There are several different sets of rules for scoring Go, which one are you trying to implement?

Comment: I want to use japanese set of rules, where final score is a sum of size of territory and number of captured stones. I do not know how to identify the dead stones (stones inside the territory of opponent).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a non-trivial question because usually a Go game ends before players make all of the moves necessary to make it obvious what the "true" score/value of the game is. And sometimes it's possible that the value of the game will be different assuming that one player played suboptimally (e.g. letting opponent finish establishing a set of stones that has life in opponent's territory, even though it's provably possible to kill the set of stones). Counting raw un-intruded territory is fairly obvious, just check whether each space is "cut off" in each possible combination of directions (positive and negative horizontal and vertical) by either the edges of the board or pieces of one color. You can do this more efficiently by starting a breadth first search starting at an empty spot, and keep track of which colors are encountered in the process (not traversing BFS from an occupied spot), and once no more empty spots can be found then if the colored pieces found are all one color, then all the empty spaces found belong to that color, otherwise they don't belong to anyone. Then continue the breadth first search with the next unexplored empty spot, removing all previously explored empty spots. However, if the opponent has one piece in established territory, that piece should ideally be ignored in calculating territory, and in fact even be considered captured. The situation is the same if it is obvious that a group of opponent's pieces in a player's territory will "eventually" be captured if they play it out without making mistakes. The situation is even more delicate if the two players get into a situation where they each have a group of pieces adjacent to the other's pieces, such that the pieces have "mutual life", i.e. if one player tries to make a move in an effort to kill the other's pieces then the opponent will be able to kill the original player's pieces, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @user256...'s answer, there are some high-level concepts that might help you decide how in-depth to make your Go score estimation:

1. **Life** - A group needs two eyes to live. If a group is otherwise surrounded and doesn't have 2 eyes, it might be dead.
2. **Group count ordering** - Just as gameplay generally starts in the corners, moves to the sides, then finishes in the middle, this order is also the simplest way to start counting the score. A corner only needs two walls to create territory, the sides 3 walls, and the center 4 walls.
3. **Line number** - Groups with stones closest to the edge of the board are more likely to be established territory in a score estimation: "Line 4 is for 'influence', Line 3 is for 'territory'" is a common Go proverb. Thus, starting counting from the corners, but count the stones closest to the edge of the board first. There might not be any stones on the first line, but there might be a few on the second line.